# php script-wise breakdown of huge XML for parsing

Tags: php, parsing, memory-limit

I've got a few huge XML files, and I cut a few rows out, so I could have a manageable-sized file on which to test my parsing script, written in php. There is a lot of nesting in the XML file, there are a lot of columns, and there are a lot of blanks, so writing the script was this huge ordeal. Now, I'm hitting my php memory limit on the full-sized XML files I want to parse.

Now, one thing I've considered is temporarily upping the php memory limit, but I need to rerun this script every well... week or so. Also, I don't have the best system. Running it hot and setting it melt is an all-to-real possibility and one of my "perfect storms".

I also considered attempting to learn a new language, such as perl or python. I probably could use to know one of these languages, anyway. I would prefer to stick with what I have, though, if only in the interest of time.

Isn't there some way to have php break the XML file up into manageable chunks that won't push my machine to its limit? Because every row in the XML file is wrapped by an ID column, it seems like I should be able to cut to the nth row closure, parse what was sliced, and then sleep, or something?

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you parsing the XML right now, SimpleXML?  You can process the XML file without reading the whole thing into memory if you use the [XML Parser Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).  They are more complex but has the positive benefit of reduced memory usage since you handle the elements as you read chunks of the file.

Comment: @drew010, when I get to my workstation, I can post a sample. I believe I used simpleXML or something similar, but I haven't ripped the code apart recently enough to say for sure.

Comment: Ok if you comment back when you post it, I'll see the response.  If its SimpleXML (which will be easy to tell), then you basically are parsing the entire file into a large structure so it takes a lot of memory.

Comment: Looks like I'm using xpath: `
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);`

Comment: Is `$doc` the entire XML source?

Comment: @drew010 Yes, it is.  I currently am only parsing one file at a time, and the file is $doc.  I don't believe that I will ever need to parse more than one file at a time using this script's main function.